# NSViewController Delegate

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield

I tried to register a delegate for a NSViewController like this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController ,  NSTextFieldDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textfield.delegate = self
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: NSTextField!

    func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
    { print ("text did change ")
    }
}
```

the func textDidChange is not called, if the textfield changes its content.

In the Storyboard I made the following connections:

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that the text field is connected to your `textfield` outlet?

Comment: I think I did. I added a screenshot above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textDidChange` isn't part of `NSTextFieldDelegate`, it's part of `NSTextDelegate`, and it's typically used for `NSTextView`s, not `NSTextField`s.

`NSTextFieldDelegate` adopts `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`, including `controlTextDidChange`, which is what you're looking for.

```
override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    print( "text did change" )
}
```

Note that you can set the delegate either via Storyboard outlet, or via code, but you don't need to do both (I prefer the former, but it's totally subjective which is superior).

Comment: Nope, setting the delegate twice doesn't hurt anything, it's just unnecessary.  Worst case: at some point in the future, you decide to change the delegate to something else, and only remember to change it in one of the places, and subsequently spend hours trying to figure out why it's not working right.